Using XC32 for Unit Tests with Ceedling for Embedded C - Cannot build
I am trying to set up a Test Driven Development workflow for myself using Ceedling - https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/blob/master/docs/CeedlingPacket.md
My project is using a PIC32MX575F256H. Currently, the project is empty of any code I have written myself.
My YAML script for Ceedling is below. I have also included a copy of the shell output I get when I try to run it.
    \[12:18:12\] user@mypc:\~/MPLAB$ ceedling --trace test:all

    Test 'test_main.c'
    -

    In file included from /opt/microchip/xc32/v4.35/pic32mx/include/xc.h:376,
         from src/config/default/device.h:47,
         from src/config/default/peripheral/gpio/plib_gpio.h:45,
         from src/config/default/definitions.h:52,
         from test/test_main.c:10:
    /opt/microchip/xc32/v4.35/pic32mx/include/proc/PIC32MX/p32mx575f256h.h:29106:10: fatal error: proc/ppic32mx.h: No such file or directory
    29106 | #include "proc/ppic32mx.h"
          |     ^\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
    compilation terminated.
    ERROR: Shell command failed.

    > Shell executed command:
    > 'gcc -E -I"/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/simulation" -I"test/support" -I"src" -I"src/config" -I"src/config/default" -I"src/config/default/PIC32MX_DFP" -I"src/config/default/default.mhc" -I"src/config/default/peripheral" -I"src/config/default/peripheral/clk" -I"src/config/default/peripheral/evic" -I"src/config/default/peripheral/gpio" -I"src/config/default/stdio" -I"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.35/pic32mx/include" -D__PIC32MX_\_ -D__32MX575F256H_\_ -D__LANGUAGE_C_\_ -DUNITY_INT_WIDTH=32 -DCMOCK_MEM_INDEX_TYPE=uint32_t -DCMOCK_MEM_PTR_AS_INT=uint32_t -DCMOCK_MEM_SIZE=2056 -DTEST -D__PIC32MX_\_ -D__32MX575F256H_\_ -D__LANGUAGE_C_\_ -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "test/test_main.c" -o "build/test/preprocess/files/test_main.c"'
    > And exited with status: \[1\].

    rake aborted!
    ShellExecutionException: ShellExecutionException
    /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/ceedling:23:in `load' /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/ceedling:23:in `\<main\>'
    Tasks: TOP =\> test:all
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    ERROR: Ceedling Failed


   :project:
        :use_exceptions: FALSE
        :use_test_preprocessor: TRUE
        :use_auxiliary_dependencies: TRUE
        :build_root: build
        #  :release_build: TRUE
        :test_file_prefix: test_
        :which_ceedling: gem
        :ceedling_version: 0.31.1
        :default_tasks:
        - test:all

    #:test_build:
        #  :use_assembly: TRUE

    #:release_build:
        #  :output: MyApp.out
        #  :use_assembly: FALSE

    :environment:
        - :mcu:  32MX575F256L
        - :freq: 80000000UL

    :extension:
        :executable: .elf

    :paths:
        :test:
        - +:test/**
        - -:test/support
    :source:
        - src/**
    :support:
        - test/support
    :libraries: []
    :include:
        - "/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.35/pic32mx/include/"

    :defines:

        :common: &common_defines 
            - __PIC32MX__
            - __32MX575F256H__
            - __LANGUAGE_C__
        :test:
            - *common_defines
            - UNITY_INT_WIDTH=32
            - CMOCK_MEM_INDEX_TYPE=uint32_t
            - CMOCK_MEM_PTR_AS_INT=uint32_t
            - CMOCK_MEM_SIZE=2056
            - TEST
         :test_preprocess:
            - *common_defines
            - TEST

    :cmock:
        :mock_prefix: mock_
        :when_no_prototypes: :warn
        :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
        :plugins:
            - :ignore
            - :callback
        :treat_as:
            uint8:    HEX8
            uint16:   HEX16
            uint32:   UINT32
            int8:     INT8
            bool:     UINT8

    :gcov:
        :reports:
        - HtmlDetailed
    :gcovr:
        :html_medium_threshold: 75
        :html_high_threshold: 90

    :libraries:
        :placement: :end
        :flag: "-l${1}"
        :path_flag: "-L ${1}"
        :system: []    # for example, you might list 'm' to grab the math library
        :test: []
        :release: []

    :tools:
        :test_compiler:
            :executable: "/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.35/bin/xc32-gcc"
            :arguments:
               - -mprocessor=32MX575F256L
               - -x c
               - -c
               - "${1}"
               - -o "${2}"
               - -D$: COLLECTION_DEFINES_TEST_AND_VENDOR
               - -I"$": COLLECTION_PATHS_TEST_SUPPORT_SOURCE_INCLUDE_VENDOR
               - -Iinclude/
               - -Wall
        :test_linker: 
            :executable: "/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.35/bin/xc32-gcc"
            :arguments:
                - -mprocessor=32MX575F256L
                - -gdwarf-3
                - -D"$": COLLECTION_DEFINES_TEST_AND_VENDOR
                - -I"$": COLLECTION_PATHS_TEST_SUPPORT_SOURCE_INCLUDE_VENDOR
                - -Wl,-Map="${3}"
                - -o"./build/ceedling/generated/test/out/test_build.elf"
                - "{'${1}'.split(' ').map { |x| (x.include? '/out/c/') ? (Pathname(x).sub_ext('.p1')).to_s : x }.join(' ') }"
                - "${4}"
   
            
    :test_fixture:
        :executable: ruby
        :name: "Microchip simulator test fixture"
        :stderr_redirect: :win #inform Ceedling what model of $stderr capture to use
        :arguments:
            - test/simulation/sim_test_fixture.rb
                   

    :plugins:
        :load_paths:
            - "#{Ceedling.load_path}"
        :enabled:
            - stdout_pretty_tests_report
            - module_generator


My project builds okay when I try through MPLAB X IDE; however, I am not too familiar with calling the compiler directly from the command line and am having trouble getting things to work as they should. As far as I can tell, the includes in my YAML should cover the missing files but apparently that isn't happening.
I have tried following tihs guide but it does not seem to have fixed my issues: https://github.com/crespum/Ceedling-PIC32

I have noticed ceedling is using the wrong complier.
MPLAB puts out:
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.35/bin/xc32-gcc"  -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32MX575F256L -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/default" -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1360937237/main.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1360937237/main.o ../src/main.c  -DXPRJ_default=default   -mdfp="/home/user/.mchp_packs/Microchip/PIC32MX_DFP/1.6.369"
I'm not convinced the commands are the same. For some reason ceedling insists on using gcc even though I explicitly ask it to use xc32-gcc.

I'm not an expert myself in Ceedling, but I'll try to point out some things that caught my attention:

If I'm not mistaken, :test_fixture: is part of the :tools: , so place it similarly to test_linker and test_compiler.

ceedling paths:include will show you all the included paths.

I don't see you including proc/ anywhere in your project.yml file. If it's somewhere deeper down in that path, try using /opt/microchip/xc32/v4.35/pic32mx/include/** (note ** )so that it knows to look deeper.

You can also give Ceedling a path (under environment: path: ) to look for compiler/linker, etc., so that you don't have to use paths for executable in tools.


P.S.  Ceedling insists on using gcc because it is the default linker/compiler, meaning your tools section is not correct and it can't find xc32-gcc at all.
